# USB speakers not working, but only for apps' sounds (19.04)

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, speakers

I've recently purchased a set of Audioengine USB speakers. They work great, but not with Ubuntu (19.04).

Specifically, they are displayed in the Settings and when I run the sound test they work fine, but they are silent when the sound is generated by any app.

My headphones instead work fine on the same machine.

I already tried to reset pulseaudio's setting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set them to be the master (default) playback option.

Install pavucontrol, and start generating sound from some app.

Open pavucontrol, then in the Playback tab (source), change the output audio device (for that stream only) to the USB device.

Comment: this does not help